# jQuery CSS opacity overriding

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a popup for which I am using jQuery's CSS function.Here's the code:

```
function Show_Popup(action, userid) {
 $('#content').css("opacity","0.7");
 $('#window').fadeIn('fast');
 $('#window').css("opacity","1.0");}
```

Here #window is inside #content.Hence when it "fades in",its opacity is also set to 0.7,which I am trying to override via the 3rd line of code.But its not working.Any way around this?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 $('#content').css("opacity","0.7");
 $('#window').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $('#window').css("opacity","1.0");}
  });
```

also you might want to consider $.animate() if thats what you're looking for.

**Remember:** CSS-Opacity is chaining. So even if #window has an opacity of 100% its only a 100% from the 70% opacity of its parent..
See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/ for a hackish  workaround

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this, unfortunately. At least, no tidy way.

See, `#window` is being set to 100% of `#content`'s 70%.

The only way around this is to have `#window` not be inside `#content`, but rather afterward/on top of.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a better/different idea.

If you can, set `position: absolute` on the `#window`. Make sure it doesn't cause problems with the flow, but if you do that then the `opacity` doesn't chain anymore.

Comment: no dude mine is already absolute!still not working...heres the full code   http://pastebin.com/nxDhtrLU
see from lines 190 onwards

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeTo()

```
$('#window').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
```